# Binding with service variable using ControllerAs syntax without $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch, angularjs-controlleras

I'm familiarizing myself with controllerAs syntax in AngularJS, and I've come to a problem when I need to do a simple binding to a service variable. Typically a `$scope.$watch` or `$scope.$on` would do, but that would involve injecting `$scope`, which seems to defeat the purpose of controllerAs.

Currently what I have is that after clicking one of the buttons and calling `config.setAttribute(attr)`, the controller calls the service's `setAttribute` function, but not `getAttribute`, so `config.attribute` never changes.

Is there something I'm overlooking in how I'm approaching this? Would I need to inject `$scope` or change the controller syntax to use `$scope` instead?

**View:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="ConfigCtrl as config">
    <h3>Customize</h3>
    <pre>Current attribute: {{config.attribute}}</pre>

    <label>Attributes</label>
    <div data-ng-repeat="attr in config.attributes">
        <button ng-click="config.setAttribute(attr)">{{attr.name}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Service:**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
.factory('Customization', Customization);

function Customization() {
    var service = {
        attribute: null,
        getAttributes: getAttributes,
        setAttribute: setAttribute,
        getAttribute: getAttribute
    }
    return service;
    /////
    function getAttributes() {
        return [
            {name: 'Attr1', value: '1'},
            {name: 'Attr2', value: '2'} // etc.
        ];
    }

    function setAttribute(attr) {
        service.attribute = attr;
    }

    function getAttribute() {
        return service.attribute;
    }
}})();
```

**Controller:**

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
.controller('ConfigCtrl', ConfigCtrl);

function ConfigCtrl(Customization){
    var vm = this;

    vm.attribute = Customization.getAttribute(); // bind
    vm.attributes = [];

    // Functions
    vm.setAttribute = Customization.setAttribute;

    init();
    /////
    function init(){
        // Get attributes array
        vm.attributes = Customization.getAttributes();
    }
}})();
```

Comment: Injecting `$scope` doesn't defeat the purpose of controllerAs. That's kind of the point - that you inject `$scope` when it is needed as a service for things like `$watch` and `$on` and not by default in order to publish ViewModel properties.

Comment: http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/angularjs-using-watch-with-controlleras

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they definitely cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my controller looks like after injecting `$scope` and adding the watch for `attribute`:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
.controller('ConfigCtrl', ConfigCtrl);

function ConfigCtrl($scope, Customization){
    var vm = this;

    vm.attribute;
    vm.attributes = [];

    // Functions
    vm.setAttribute = Customization.setAttribute;

    init();
    /////
    function init(){
        // Get attributes array
        vm.attributes = Customization.getAttributes();
    }

    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return Customization.getAttribute()
    }, function() {
        vm.attribute = Customization.getAttribute();
    });

}})();
```

I also have the Karma test in case anyone is interested:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    describe('ConfigCtrl', function () {

        var ConfigCtrl, scope;

        beforeEach(module('app'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ConfigCtrl = $controller('ConfigCtrl',
                {$scope: scope}
            );
        }));

        describe('#setAttribute', function(){
            it('sets the current attribute', function(){
                var selected = {
                    name:'Attr1',
                    value:'1'
                };
                ConfigCtrl.setAttribute(selected);
                scope.$apply();
                expect(ConfigCtrl.attribute).to.eql(selected);
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

Thanks for the help. I'm welcome to any better answers anyone else might have.

Comment: I know this question is a little bit older. So just as a hint: don't use the implicit injection if you want to minify your code. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation